# Is this the correct way to update a propery in objects array state

Tags: reactjs

I've got the code below and i wanna update name property in the object that has id 1. I'm updating with the code `objArray[1].name = "Xxx"`. It perfectly works but is this correct? Should i use prevState with setObjArray. That looked so much easier what you think?

```
const [objArray, setObjArray] = useState([
    {
            id:1,
            name:"Eren"
    },
    {
            id:2,
            name:"Eren2"
    },
    {
            id:3,
            name:"Eren3"
    }
```

])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not advisable. You have the useState second array element (setObjArray) for updating state. Read documentation for [React useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) . There are two basic ways but there isn't much difference. First method;

```
  const changeName = (id, newName) => {
    // map through the array and change the name of the element with the id you are targeting
    const changedArr = objArray.map((element) => {
      if (element.id === id) {
        return {
          ...element,
          name: newName,
        };
      } else {
        return element;
      }
    });
    // set the returned array as you new state 
    setObjArray(changedArr)
  };
```

Second method;

- You have access to the previous state. This way you can make changes on the previous state and return the new array as your new state.

```
 const newChangeName = (id, newName) => {
    setObjArray((prev) => {
      // map through the array and change the name of the element with the id you are targeting
      // set the returned array as you new state
      return prev.map((element) => {
        if (element.id === id) {
          return {
            ...element,
            name: newName,
          };
        } else {
          return element;
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: But this way state doesnt update immediately

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Let me share one way to do this:

1. Make a shallow copy of the array

```js
let temp_state = [...objArray];
```

2. Make a shallow copy of the element you want to mutate

```js
let temp_element = { ...temp_state[0] };
```

3. Update the property you're interested in

```js
temp_element.name = "new name";
```

4. Put it back into our array. N.B. we *are* mutating the array here, but that's why we made a copy first

```js
temp_state[0] = temp_element;
```

5. Set the state to our new copy

```js
setObjArray(temp_state);
```